# AWS S3 Redirection rules not letting me saving it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I tried to create an image resizer lambda function and for that I use S3 bucket for storage, but when I try to add Redirection rules under S3 properties it does not allow me to save it. It keep giving me error

```
(Unknown Error
An unexpected error occurred.
API response
Expected params.WebsiteConfiguration.RoutingRules to be an Array)
```

**this is the redirect rule I'm trying to add**

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals/>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <Protocol>https</Protocol>
            <HostName>API-endpoint</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>prod/resize?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
            <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 22):

**GOT IT WORKING**

Following definition works:

```json
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "404"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "Protocol": "https",
            "HostName": "<host>",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "<prefix>",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "307"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: There has been a small change in user interface of AWS S3 bucket overview. Take care about adding the bucket policy in "Redirection rules" section.

Answer (score 7):

To create redirection rules in the new Amazon S3 console, you must use JSON.

Comment: Also, watch out for JSON syntax. I had a trailing comma by mistake, but still got the "rules definition must be an array". The validating step didn't tell me that the JSON was plainly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "Sid". See if it is identical to another "Sid" of another policy, even for a different bucket. If it is, change it.

Answer (score -4):

Go to the **[S3 console](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets)** and select your bucket. Select the **Permission tab**. Then go to the **Bucket policy**. push the edit button and add the following to the **Bucket policy**. Then **replace** your bucket name with **Your_Bucket_Name**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicReadAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Your_Bucket_Name/*"
    }
]}
```